# is there any javascript or swf to control sound on external as2 swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, mute, audio-player

I have a swf file which plays some sounds (flash game), unfortunately there's no mute function built in. I don't have the fla file so I can't change or add a mute button.

The swf is implemented via embed src / swfobject.js
Is there a way to mute this external swf file?
Maybe via external JS function or an additional swf file which can control the game.swf? the game.swf is AS2 compiled.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the AS2 swf source then I don't believe there's a direct way to do this but you could do a workaround by creating your own wrapper.swf in which to load the game.swf. This wrapper.swf could then control the global sound in the game.swf and could open up methods to Javascript from where you could control the sound.

I would advise making your wrapper in AS3 as, well, it makes like easier. AS2 is horrid by comparison.

I've put some basic code below that loads an external swf, with a simple button that toggles all sound within the wrapper - including loaded swfs.

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("playsound.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(req);

var btn:TextField = new TextField();
btn.text = "Toggle Sound";
btn.mouseEnabled = true;
btn.buttonMode = true;
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
this.addChild(btn);

var amMuted:Boolean = false;

function handleClick(e) {
    if (amMuted) {
        amMuted = false;

        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
    } else {
        amMuted = true;

        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
    }
}
```

you could alternatively just call:

> SoundMixer.stopAll()

if you want to mute everything.

if you want to test the princple here's a sample AS2 swf to play a generic looping sound:

```
song = new Sound();
song.loadSound("http://users.skynet.be/fa046054/home/P22/track39.mp3", true);

song.onLoad = function( success:Boolean ) { 
    if (success) { 
        song.start(); 
    } else { 
        // fail 
    }
}

// replay
song.onSoundComplete = function() {
    song.start();
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for help, due to the fact that i'm not flash programmer, do u know a good source where i can find more details for such wrapper ?

Comment: @Sascha no problem, I've expanded the answer above with some example code. Please note that this doesn't add the swf to the stage, just plays it from memory.

Comment: @Sascha did the above solve your issue or do you need further assistance?